# redirect all http https to Port server

Tags: ssl

i wanted to know , is that possible to redirect 80 and 443 all to port (Ex :888)
i able to redirect 443 to port 888 , but i want port 888 is accessible when visitor is opening on http example http://192.168.1.1 redirect to https://192.168.1.1:888

I've tried to add Redirect permanent / https://192.168.1.1 on vhost 80 configuration and 443 also added Redirect permanent / https://192.168.1.1:888

but whenever i access http://192.168.1.1:888 it got error 400 bad request

create redirect http to https and port ,and when some access http url, directly go to port